# JQuery autocomplete валидация

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть код, который берет с сервера список для автокомплита, примерно такой:

```
$("[name=autocompletefield]").autocomplete({
       url : function() {
            return url + appendDataToRequest();
        },
        onSelect : clearPreviousData,
        delay:10,
        type:'xml',
        fillin:true,
        partial:true,
        values:true,
        writable:true
    });
```

С JQuery плохо знаком и по документации не могу разобраться, как мне провести валидацию введенных данных?
Например, пользователь вводит текст, которого нет в списке автокомплита, следовательно должно выводится сообщение об ошибке, как этого добиться?

Буду очень благодарен примеру.

Comment: О каком плагине идет речь? В "стандартном", который поставляется с jqueryUi источник обозначен как source, а не как url.

Comment: Используйте валидацию после установки значения. Поставьте проверку после ввода, т.е. на изменение поля проверяйте переменную, которая задается в onSelect

Answer (score 1):

Может стоит по подробнее написать? Есть [хороший пример](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) в документации JQuery UI. Судя по коду от сервера приходит xml возможных вариантов (то, что предположительно может ввести пользователь), так? Если да, то, возможно, стоит распарсить этот xml и если пользователь изменяет значение input'а (отловить можно с помощью стандартных событий библиотеки) циклом сверять введенный текст и варианты из xml и сравнивать - нашли совпадение (например 3 первых буквы из input`а и из xml ответа сервера) показать возможный вариант. Я бы сделал так.